# Highcharts not displaying categories from php array

Tags: php, arrays, highcharts

I really need help with this one. I'm bleeding my eyes out for two days and I can't see the solution to my problem.

I'm building two arrays in php and than joining them to one array and after that trying to display some data in a highcharts and I'm getting an error and chart is not displaying. When I debug the data I can see the result is generated, but chart is not displaying. Can someone point me to the right direction.

Error message I'm getting is:

```
 SyntaxError: missing ] after element list[Learn More] potrazivanja_dugovanja.php:824:4015
note: [ opened at line 823, column 25
```

This is chart:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    //Chart to display potraživanja

    Highcharts.chart('potrazivanja_po_partneru', {

        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Potraživanja po partneru'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: [
                <?php
                foreach($master_array as $key => $value) {
                    if(!empty($value['naziv_kupca'])) {
                        $naziv_kupca = $value['naziv_kupca'];
                    } else {
                        $naziv_kupca = 'X';
                    }
                        echo "'" . json_encode($naziv_kupca) . "', ";
                }
                ?>
            ]
        }],
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Potraživanje'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            reversed: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Nije u valuti',
            data: [
                <?php
                    foreach($master_array as $key => $value) {
                        if(!empty($value['not_late'])) {
                            $not_late = $value['not_late'];
                        } else {
                            $not_late = 0;
                        }
                            echo $not_late . ', ';
                    }
                ?>
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Dospijeva danas',
            data: [
                <?php
                    foreach($master_array as $key => $value) {
                        if(!empty($value['late'])) {
                            $late = $value['late'];
                        } else {
                            $late = 0;
                        }
                            echo $late . ', ';
                    }
                ?>
            ]
        }]
    });

});
```

And this is how I generate an array in PHP:

```
    $invoiced_array[] = array('naziv_kupca' => $row['kupac'], 'not_late' => decimal_convert(round(($row['ukupno']),2)));
$late_array[] = array('naziv_kupca' => $row1['kupac'], 'late' => decimal_convert(round(($row1['ukupno']),2)));
//Join array
                                                    function merge_two_arrays($array1,$array2) {
                                                        $data = array();
                                                        $arrayAB = array_merge($array1,$array2);
                                                        foreach ($arrayAB as $value) {
                                                            $id = $value['naziv_kupca'];
                                                            if (!isset($data[$id])) {
                                                                $data[$id] = array();
                                                            }
                                                            $data[$id] = array_merge($data[$id],$value);
                                                        }
                                                        return $data;
                                                    }

                                                    $master_array = merge_two_arrays($invoiced_array,$late_array);
```

When I debug the code to see the result it's this:

```
    xAxis: [{
                categories: [
                    'ŽIVO obrt', 'ZVONČICA obrt za trgovinu i usluge', 'ZAPREŠIĆ D.O.O.', 'Zagrebački vrtovi j.d.o.o.', 'ZAGREBAČKI HOLDING  d.o.o.', 'xxxŠANTIĆ PROMET', 'Voger d.o.o.', 'VINKOPROM d.o.o.', 'Trgovina Tišler, obrt za trgovinu, vl.Ivana Tišler', 'Trgovina i usluge Blažević', 'Trgovačko uslužni obrt Contra', '    
Dobrovoljno vatrogasno društvo "Omiš"',                 ]
            }],
```

I can see ] in the end but highcharts don't see it. Can you explain me why, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @Budimir Skrtic, I am not `PHP` expert, but if you copy the result array to JS then you can see that it is not well constructed: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3wognpLd/

Comment: @ppotaczek , Thank you very much. You pointed me to the right direction. There was a lot of "garbage" in the text, so I had to clean it before passing it to highcharts. I will post what I did, so maybe someone else will have some help with it.